# Colouring tables - Option clash for package xcolor

Tags: color, option-clash

I would like to colour some rows of my table. However when using `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` I get the error "Option clash for package xcolor".

I am using quite a lot of packages, but I do not know with which one it clashes. Also, I would like to know what I can do to still use all my packages and highlight my table rows. Is there another option than xcolor?

Here is a list of all used packages:

```
\usepackage[b5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[superscript]{cite}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\includepdfset{offset=5mm 0mm}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath { {../figures/} }

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=small,labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,labelfont=small,labelfont=bf}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{arev}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\apptocmd{\sloppy}{\hbadness 9000\relax}{}{}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pdfpages` package loads the `eso-pic` package, which loads the `xcolor` package without any options, then when you load `xcolor` with the `[table]` option later, LaTeX tells you about the option clash:

```
The package xcolor has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [table]
Adding the global options:
  ,table
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

To fix the issue you can either add the `table` option to your `\documentclass`. *i.e.:*

```
\documentclass[table]{whatever_class_you_are_using}
```

or you can load the `xcolor` package before `pdfpages`:

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

Comment: Thank you! The second option works well (the first one, adding table to the documentclass didn't)